# Simplifying expressions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

How do you simplify the following expression?

$$Q=(1-\tan^2(x)) \left(1-\tan^2 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\cdots \left(1-\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\right)$$

I've tried the the following :
$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$

$$\cos x = \frac{\sin 2x}{2\sin x}$$

$$\tan x = \frac{2\sin^2x}{\sin2x}$$

$$Q= \left( 1- \left(\frac{2\sin^2x}{\sin2x}\right)^2\right) \left(1-\left(\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\sin x}\right)^2\right) \cdots \left(1-\left(\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}}{\sin(\frac{x}{2^n})}\right)^2\right)$$

But i have no idea how to continue.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
1-\tan^2 t=\frac{\cos^2t-\sin^2t}{\cos^2t}=\frac{\cos(2t)}{\cos^2t}
$$
and for arguments of the form $\frac{x}{2^n}$, many things will vanish in the product.

Answer (score 2):

A more straightforward hint comes from the tangent double angle formula:

$$
\tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan{x}}{1-\tan^2 x}.
$$

You'll then find you have a telescoping product.